# PyQT5 change QPushButton's StyleSheet at runtime

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

**What I want to do:** I want to change the StyleSheet background-image of a button during a second when it is clicked and then return it to it's original StyleSheet. I illustrate this with the images bellow.

[image] --button pressed-->[image]--1 second--> [image]

**My problem:** Although I can change it one time with this:

```
def bt_start_pressed(self):
        print('start')
        self.bt_start.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/resource/start-.png);")
        answer_on = write_to_plc('@00WD0000000152*')
        print(answer_on)
```

If I try to encorporate both changes of StyleSheet (change from original gray to the green lime then to gray again) like the code below, no changes to the background-image StyleSheet occur, but everything else in the code works normally. Note: the button gets initialized with the grey image.

```
    def bt_start_pressed(self):
        print('start')
        self.bt_start.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/resource/start-.png);")
        answer_on = write_to_plc('@00WD0000000152*')
        print(answer_on)
        print('start2')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.bt_start.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/resource/start.png);")
        answer_off = write_to_plc('@00WD0000000053*')
        print(answer_off)
```

I believe the snippets above are enough, in case you want to see everything in detail, the code is bellow:

The main script

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import pbl3_rc
import sys
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM4', bytesize=7, parity='E', stopbits=2, baudrate=9600)


class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__() # Call the inherited classes __init__ method
        uic.loadUi('PBL3_designer.ui', self) # Load the .ui file

        self.bt_start = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'bt_start')
        self.bt_start.clicked.connect(self.bt_start_pressed)
        self.bt_stop = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'bt_stop')
        self.bt_stop.clicked.connect(self.bt_stop_pressed)
        self.bt_motorForward = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'bt_motorForward')
        self.bt_motorForward.clicked.connect(self.bt_motorForward_pressed)
        self.bt_motorBackward = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'bt_motorBackwards')
        self.bt_motorBackward.clicked.connect(self.bt_motorBackward_pressed)
        self.bt_velUp = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'bt_velUp')
        self.bt_velUp.clicked.connect(self.bt_velUp_pressed)
        self.bt_velDown = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'bt_velDown')
        self.bt_velDown.clicked.connect(self.bt_velDown_pressed)

        self.show() # Show the GUI

    def bt_start_pressed(self):
        print('start')
        self.bt_start.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/resource/start-.png);")
        answer_on = write_to_plc('@00WD0000000152*')
        print(answer_on)
        print('start2')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.bt_start.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/resource/start.png);")
        answer_off = write_to_plc('@00WD0000000053*')
        print(answer_off)

    def bt_stop_pressed(self):
        print('stop')
        self.bt_stop.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/resource/stop-.png);")
        answer_on = write_to_plc('@00WD0002000150*')
        print(answer_on)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.bt_stop.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/resource/stop.png);")
        answer_off = write_to_plc('@00WD0002000051*')
        print(answer_off)
        print('stop2')

    def bt_motorForward_pressed(self):
        print('forward')
        self.bt_motorForward.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/resource/motorForward-.png);")
        answer_on = write_to_plc('@00WD0003000151*')
        print(answer_on)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.bt_motorForward.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/resource/motorForward.png);")
        answer_off = write_to_plc('@00WD0003000050*')
        print(answer_off)
        print('forward2')

    def bt_motorBackward_pressed(self):
        print('backward')
        self.bt_motorBackward.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/resource/motorBackwards-.png);")
        answer_on = write_to_plc('@00WD0004000156*')
        print(answer_on)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.bt_motorBackward.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/resource/motorBackwards.png);")
        answer_off = write_to_plc('@00WD0004000057*')
        print(answer_off)
        print('backward2')

    def bt_velUp_pressed(self):
        print('velUp')
        self.bt_velUp.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/resource/velUp-.png);")
        answer_on = write_to_plc('@00WD0005000157*')
        print(answer_on)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.bt_velUp.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/resource/velUp.png);")
        answer_off = write_to_plc('@00WD0005000056*')
        print(answer_off)
        print('velUp2')

    def bt_velDown_pressed(self):
        print('velDown')
        self.bt_velDown.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/resource/velDown-.png);")
        answer_on = write_to_plc('@00WD0006000154*')
        print(answer_on)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.bt_velDown.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/resource/velDown.png);")
        answer_off = write_to_plc('@00WD0006000055*')
        print(answer_off)
        print('velDown2')


def write_to_plc(trama):
    s = (trama + chr(13)).encode('utf8')
    ser.write(s)
    serial.timeout = 0.1
    resposta = (ser.read_until(chr(13), size=10))
    serial.timeout = 0.1
    return resposta


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui()
app.exec_()
```

And the .ui code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>556</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="picbox_set_cinza1">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>70</x>
      <y>370</y>
      <width>101</width>
      <height>101</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="pixmap">
     <pixmap resource="pbl3.qrc">:/resource/set_box.png</pixmap>
    </property>
    <property name="scaledContents">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="bt_velUp">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>710</x>
      <y>320</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-image: url(:/resource/velUp.png);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="flat">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="bt_velDown">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>710</x>
      <y>370</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-image: url(:/resource/velDown.png);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="flat">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="bt_motorBackwards">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>600</x>
      <y>340</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-image: url(:/resource/motorBackwards.png);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="flat">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="bt_stop">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>690</x>
      <y>220</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-image: url(:/resource/stop.png);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="flat">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="picbox_logo">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>580</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>101</width>
      <height>101</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>LogoEmpresa</string>
    </property>
    <property name="scaledContents">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="picbox_set_cinza2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>220</x>
      <y>370</y>
      <width>101</width>
      <height>101</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="pixmap">
     <pixmap resource="pbl3.qrc">:/resource/set_box.png</pixmap>
    </property>
    <property name="scaledContents">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_set_cinza1">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>80</x>
      <y>340</y>
      <width>91</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Yu Gothic UI Semibold</family>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>1º Conjunto Cinza</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_set_cinza2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>230</x>
      <y>340</y>
      <width>91</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Yu Gothic UI Semibold</family>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>2º Conjunto Cinza</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QProgressBar" name="progbar_set_cinza2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>220</x>
      <y>480</y>
      <width>118</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="value">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="bt_start">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>630</x>
      <y>220</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-image: url(:/resource/start-.png);
background-image: url(:/resource/start.png);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="flat">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="pb_robotinoPose">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>80</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>451</width>
      <height>211</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>TextLabel</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QProgressBar" name="progbar_set_cinza1">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>80</x>
      <y>480</y>
      <width>118</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="value">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="bt_close">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>720</x>
      <y>530</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Close</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="lbl_set_cores">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>380</x>
      <y>340</y>
      <width>101</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Yu Gothic UI Semibold</family>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Conjunto Colorido</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="bt_motorForward">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>650</x>
      <y>340</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-image: url(:/resource/motorForward.png);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="flat">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QProgressBar" name="progbar_set_cores1">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>380</x>
      <y>480</y>
      <width>118</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="value">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="picbox_set_cores2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>370</x>
      <y>370</y>
      <width>101</width>
      <height>101</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="pixmap">
     <pixmap resource="pbl3.qrc">:/resource/set_box.png</pixmap>
    </property>
    <property name="scaledContents">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="picbox_logoIPCA">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>690</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>101</width>
      <height>101</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="pixmap">
     <pixmap resource="pbl3.qrc">:/resource/logoIPCA.png</pixmap>
    </property>
    <property name="scaledContents">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="pbl3.qrc"/>
  <include location="../../.designer/backup/pbl3.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: There's something unclear from your question. While you seem to be asking about a delayed state, the second snippet sends two different messages. Now, those are two very distinct aspects and problems: 1. from the UX perspective, showing a button that "releases" after being "phisically" released is terribly wrong: the user might click again by mistake and won't be able to understand if the button has been released in the exact moment, and/or if they actually send two different messages, which can be a serious issue: what should happen if the user presses the button twice very fast?

Comment: The user *must* understand the difference, and just showing a delayed state is incredibly confusing. Many people would think that it's just "stuck" and they would try to press it again, with unexpected/unwanted results. This is also a problem due to the behavior of buttons, which are released when mouse moves outside their shape. 2. if sending those messages requires a delay, not only it shouldn't be done like that (blocking functions must **never** be used in the main thread), but it should also correspond to a "physical" state of the button, which could be very confusing for the issue above.

Comment: Thank you for your input @musicamante. What I pretend to do is: when the button is pressed, for it to change momentarily the background-image StyleSheet and send a message through my serial port and, after a minimal interval (the same as the background-image switch time) to send another message through the serial port. English is not my mother tongue so I can try to explain differently in case these explanations weren't clear and/or precise of what I am struggling with

Comment: The problem still remains: first of all, "pressed" and "clicked" are two very different things. Then, again, what should happen if the user pressed/clicked the button and does it again *before* the second message is sent? Even if you manage that by code, that should be visually clear to the user.

Comment: Ok, so I used to work with Windows Forms and what I was trying to recreate is the mouse down and mouse up events.
So ideally I would be able to create events for the moment where the users start and the moment they release the button

Comment: Then you don't need to complicate things: use the [`pressed`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#pressed) and [`released`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#released) signals, and just use proper [pseudo-states](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states) in stylesheets instead of continuously change them, specifically `QPushButton:pressed { ... }` to specify the image shown when the button is *down*. Besides that, you *must* be aware that it's standard convention to consider a button actually *clicked* only when the mouse button is released *inside* it.

Comment: That aspect is really, really important: that behavior is done to allow users the possibility to avoid clicking by mistake (so they can "cancel" the pressure just by moving the mouse outside of the geometry and release the mouse button without triggering the click action). This is a well known aspect that is considered convention since decades, and if your button should actually act on press and release, you must find a way to make it clear to users, otherwise they will expect the standard behavior and won't understand what exactly is happening. A visual hint of some kind will seriously help.

Comment: @musicamante since this are just comments I can't highlight it as an answer, but I upvoted all your comments. Thank you for your time and patience :)

Comment: second click makes get back origin you want or after 1 second get origin self
which one you want ?